# Stop form refreshing when validation fails Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel, validation, authentication

I have the following code:

**Modal:**

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
    <div class="modal fade" id="signinModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        @include('application.errors')
        ...
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-hp-modal underline btn-signup-modal">Log in</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function login( Request $request ) {
    ...
    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful
    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}

protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{   
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
    ]); 
}
```

**application.errors:**

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

The issue I am having is that after I click on `Log in`, it refreshes the page regardless of successful or unsuccessful validation. The message appears if I open the modal after the page is refreshed, but I would like the modal to stay in case it actually goes into `sendFailedLoginResponse`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you can't do that with php only, you need to submit your form with `ajax`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stop the page from refreshing on submit, you need to have a client-side validation check with JavaScript.

And to prevent the form from submitting, you need to use `event.preventDefault()` or a `return false` on your form submit handler.

It looks like you're submitting to your server here, which means you cannot do what you want. If you want to achieve a client-side validation and prevent page reload when it fails, you must use JavaScript.

Here is a pseudocode example:

```
$('#form').submit(function (e) {
    if ($('#username').value() === '') {
        // Show some validation message here...

        // Prevent default and return.
        return e.preventDefault();
    }

    // Submit to API via AJAX call.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**I found another way:**

Shove a `GET` request in the validation return to fetch some previous data, it won't fix the refresh, but at least you can recover data as the user gets redirected:

```
   // if the validator fails, redirect back to the form
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        //let's send some data back (Orlando,Florida):
        return Redirect::to('auth/register?city=Orlando&State=Florida')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password', 'password_confirmation'));


    }else{
     //validation success
    }
```